# How to Sum these Values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have repeated number of invoice in my SQL table and i want to calculate the sum of Total Amount

Like My SQL Table is

```
Invoice_No      Sub_Total     Total
10001           1265          1265
10001           1265          1265
10002           1586          1586
```

I want Sum of all of my invoices with the SQL query but i don't want to calculate All rows with same invoice number i want to calculate it one time.

Example the SUM of Total is 4116 with this query `Select SUM(Total) From Purchase_Order_Log`

I want the result should be 2851

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your table design. A table of invoices should contain each invoice just once. But you are storing the invoices redundantly. You should normalize your tables. With the table given: What value to add when I find invoice 10003 once with a total of 1234 and once with a total of 2345? The smaller value, the bigger one, the avarage, the sum ...?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Oracle? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? MySQL? ... Please always tag SQL questions with the DBMS.

Comment: Microsoft SQL SERVER 2014

Comment: Okay, I've added the tags for you. As mentioned: you should fix your data model rather than trying to write cumbersome queries to deal with it. Ask, if you need help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
  SELECT SUM(Total), Invoice_No FROM (
    SELECT distinct Invoice_No, Total from Purchase_Order_Log) as Purchase_Order_Log
    group by Invoice_No
```

which returns:

```
1265    10001
1586    10002
```

The distinct clause in the derived table ensures that only distinct invoices are selected.  This groups the totals by invoices.  If you just want a total then it is:

```
SELECT SUM(Total) from (select distinct total,invoice_no from Purchase_Order_Log) as Purchase_Order_Log
```

which returns:

```
2851
```

The second query assumes that invoice_no and total are always the same on each row.

Comment: it returns the same result nothing change.

Comment: What returns the same result? The first query should return two rows and the second query should return one row (the second query returns a grand total).

Comment: First Query Returns 4116 with Invoice_no
Second Query Returns 4116

Comment: The second query returns the result you want?

Comment: No both queries result 4116

Comment: No they don't.  I have specified what each query returns after retesting (see my edit).  I tested using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: It returns 2851 if total is same in the same Invoice_no, if i give discount on 1 item then result is different

Comment: @Usama: What does this mean " if i give discount on 1 item"? Again: It seems your data model is inappropriate. You should fix this.

Comment: The query is working :) i was just checking if amount is different in same invoice_no

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
select Sum(Total) from(
    Select Invoice_No, Total From Purchase_Order_Log
    group by Invoice_No, Total
) as T
```

Comment: Don't use `GROUP BY` when you are not aggregating. Use `DISTINCT` instead, as alreay shown by w0051977.